# Safety of pointer arithmatic on inherited objects

Tags: c++, memory, standards

If we have the following code:

```
struct Base
{
    int x;
    int y;
    void foo();
    virtual unsigned getCrc() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    int a;
    int b;
    unsigned getCrc();
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    float a;
    float b;
    unsigned getCrc();
};
```

Is it C++ standard that `a` and `b` should be after `x` and `y` in memory?
Or it is the most used method for laying out inherited objected? (i.e. compiler defacto-standard).

In other words, can I guarantee that:

```
Derived1 obj;

    int* unsafe_internal_a = (int*)((unsigned)(&obj) + sizeof(Base));
```

**EDIT**: My question is 'Is memory layout covered in some standard? Or it is compiler dependent?'. The code is just for illustration.

Comment: AFAIK, `a` and `b` will always be after `x` and `y` but there can be padding bytes added anywhere the compiler chooses to.

Comment: The order of the members in a structure or class is retained, padding may be introduced between them, though.

Comment: Are you getting the correct value of _a_? Isn't _Derived1_ supposed to also have a pointer to vtable?

Comment: You are trying to access the private members of the base class? That is suspect in itself, and hints at some design flaws. :-) What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Edited to access public members and edit code example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is:  they are compiler dependent in certain situations, and not in others.  [Details within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects)

If you need to extract data from a class, and compact it to a minimum format, I suggest implementing a set of [serialize/deserialize methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for them.  If you are just trying to figure out what c++ does, the question linked should help a lot.

Comment: Memory layout article talks about Microsoft Visual C++. MSVC is the farthest compiler from standards.

Comment: @Yousf, I agree that MSVC may not be the most compliant compiler, but the answer linked has more than just the MSVC explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This would be safer

```
size_t off = offsetof( Derived1, a );
Derived1 obj;

unsigned* unsafe_internal_a = (unsigned*)((char *)(&obj) + off);
```

Comment: No, [offsetof will only work for POD objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129894/why-cant-you-use-offsetof-on-non-pod-strucutures-in-c)