# What is this function template in this class template doing?

Tags: c++

I'm working my way through a C++ class template in a book I'm reading, and while most of it is clear, this particular function is really bugging me:

```
template <typename T> 
struct Vector3 {

T x; T y; T z;

//... several methods, constructors, etc

//Then this one, which is really confusing me:

template <typename P> 
P* Write(P* pData)
   {
    Vector3<T>* pVector = (Vector3<T>*) pData; 
    *pVector++ = *this;
    return (P*) pVector;
   }
```

First things first, this function appears to be treating an array of P or a pointer to P as if it can easily be casted from a pointer to a `Vector3`, the name of the class. How's that? If I have a `Vector3<float> someVector`, what makes a pointer to this `someVector` castable into a pointer to `float` ? (or even `int` ?) It also does the opposite: feed the function an array of floats, and then it can just cast it into an array of `Vector3`.

So that's the first area of my confusion.

Next is the `*pVector++ = *this;` -- I take it this is pointer arithmetic here, such that if `pVector` pointed to the second element in an array, with this expression we are incrementing the pointer to the next element of the array, but only *after* we first assign `*this` to the current element pointed at by `pVector`. Assuming I am correct in this, wouldn't `pVector` always point to the first element in the array, since it is just created on the previous line?! What's the purpose of the `++` operator in such a context?

Comment: It stores the contents of the Vector3 in some other place, pointed to by a pointer of *any* type. Horrible! The `++` increments the pointer to point past the stored data.

Comment: I still don't understand the casting. Is it because the `Vector3` is just a set of `floats` or whatever, that it can be treated like an array of the same type? This would assume the struct's members were aligned in memory like that of an array, unless I don't understand this conversion from `Vector3` to array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Let's decompose how it works:

1. This is the function declaration. The important point is that `P` is unrelated to `T`. So, we need to pay more attention, as some bad things might occur...

   ```
   template <typename P> 
   P* Write(P* pData)
   {
   ```

   Let's represent the memory pointed by `pData`. For the sake of the explanation, I will assume that `pData` points to a sufficiently large area in the memory (or else `Write` will probably result in a segfault), and that `Vector3<T>` is only the size of 3 `T`s. In the following, I will take `T = float`, with `sizeof(float) = 4`, but my explanations will still be valid with other types. So, here `sizeof(Vector3<float>) = 12`.

   So, here is the memory, `|-|` is one byte:

   ```
   |-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|
   ^
   |
   pData : P*
   ```
2. We interpret `pData` as a pointer to a `Vector3<T>`. This is bad style *in general*, as `P` can be anything.

   ```
       Vector3<T>* pVector = (Vector3<T>*) pData;
   ```
3. The following line:

   ```
       *pVector++ = *this;
   ```

   can be divided in:

   ```
       *pVector = *this;
       pVector++;
   ```

   - `*pVector = *this;` assign the contents of the vector (`*this`) to the data. The memory is now:

     ```
     pVector : Vector3<float>*
     |
     v
     |X|X|X|X|Y|Y|Y|Y|Z|Z|Z|Z|-|-|-|-|-|
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     copied content of the vector
     ```
   - `pVector++;` increments the vector by `1 * sizeof(Vector3<float>)`, so it now points to the non-yet-written memory:

     ```
                             pVector : Vector3<float>*
                             |
                             v
     |X|X|X|X|Y|Y|Y|Y|Z|Z|Z|Z|-|-|-|-|-|
     ```
4. `pVector` is casted back to `P*` and returned.

   ```
       return (P*) pVector;
   }
   ```

   This enables to chain writes, as a write to the returned pointer will not overwrite the first write:

   ```
   char data[2 * sizeof(Vector3<float>)];
   v2.Write(v1.Write(data));
   // now data is:
   //                                                 contents of v2
   //                                     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
   // |X1|X1|X1|X1|Y1|Y1|Y1|Y1|Z1|Z1|Z1|Z1|X2|X2|X2|X2|Y2|Y2|Y2|Y2|Z2|Z2|Z2|Z2
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   //          contents of v1
   ```

### Now, some flaws:

This function can be useful for io, and is equivalent to a `memcpy` on the vector. However, it has a lot of flaws, the major one being the template parameter. Writing directly to memory for such operations should use `char`, and not something else. Writing in memory to overwrite the content of a class (ie, not io) is a *very bad practice*, (assignment operators are made for such a task, and they are safer). Also, the following example is not self-describing:

```
vec.Write<MyTimerClass>(pointer); // Does not make sense if you are reading this line for the first time
```

Secondly, there are problems in copying memory. Here, in the explanations, I assumed `Vector3` was a simple type. It is not always the case. If it had virtual functions and members of different sizes, the layout in memory would have been implementation-defined, for example:

```
                 X, Y, Z            padding
        ------------------------    ----
|P|P|P|P|X|X|X|X|Y|Y|Y|Y|Z|Z|Z|Z|a|a|.|.
--------                        ----
 vtable                         some
 pointer                        other
                                member
```

And this is not reliable for io. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects) (the accepted answer is: "Here is how it works *for msvc*"...). And for multiple virtual inheritance it becomes a true nightmare.

**By the way, the secure implementation of such a method would have been something like**:

```
template<typename IOBuffer>
bool Write(IOBuffer& buffer)
{
    return buffer << X << Y << Z;
}
```

or better:

```
virtual bool Write(IOBufferInterface& buffer)
{
    return buffer << X << Y << Z;
}
```

It is way more simple to understand, maintain, debug, etc...

Comment: Very thorough, I appreciate it.