# Class members and member functions memory location

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

Here is a simple C++ class, named `A`:

```
class A
{
public:
    explicit A() : m_a(0) { }
    explicit A(int a) m_a(a) { }
    int getA() const { return m_a; }
    void setA(int a) { m_a = a; }

private:
    int m_a;
}
```

This is what I know so far:

- When you declare an object of a class instance, memory gets allocated for that object. The allocated memory is equivalent to the memory of its members summed up. So in my case, it is:`sizeof(A) = sizeof(int) = sizeof(m_a)`
- All member functions of class `A` are stored somewhere in memory and all instances of class `A` use the same member functions.

This is what I **don't** know:

Where are member functions stored and how are they actually stored? Let's say that an `int` for example is stored on 4 bytes; I can imagine the RAM memory layout with 4 contiguous cells each storing a part of that int. How can I imagine this layout for a function?(this could sound silly, but I imagine functions must have a place in memory because you can have a pointer point to them). Also how and where are function instructions stored? My first perception was that functions and function instructions are stored in the program executable(and its dynamic or static libraries) but if this is true what happens when you create a function pointer? AFAIK function pointers point to locations in RAM memory, can they point to locations in program binaries? If yes, how does this work?

Can anyone explain to me how this works and point out if what I know is right or wrong?

Comment: Well, you can't execute code without first loading it into RAM...

Comment: Pointers don't point to RAM, but to virtual memory.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, you need to understand the role of the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) and what are [executables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (usually executed in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) and [address spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) & [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). On Linux, read about [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall. Read also Levine's [*Linkers & Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book and [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/), and the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), and [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report and a good [C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book, with [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website.

Member functions can be virtual or plain functions.

- A plain (non `virtual`) member function is just like a C function (except that it has `this` as an implicit, often first, parameter). For example your `getA` method is implemented like the following C function (outside of the object, e.g. in the [code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of the binary executable) :

  ```
  int C$getA(A*thisptr) const { return thisptr->m_a; }
  ```

  then imagine that the compiler is translating `p->getA()` into `C$getA(p)`
- A [virtual member function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) is generally implemented thru a *vtable* ([virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)). An object with some virtual member functions (including destructor) has generally as its first (implicit) member field a pointer to such a table (generated elsewhere by the compiler). Your `class A` don't have any virtual method, but imagine if it had an additional `virtual void print(std::ostream&);` method, then your `class A` would have the same layout as

  ```
  struct A$ {
     struct A$virtualmethodtable* _vptr;
     int m_a;
  };
  ```

  and the virtual table might be

  ```
  struct A$virtualmethodtable {
    void (*print$fun) (struct A$*, std::ostream*);
  };
  ```

  (so adding other virtual functions means simply adding slot inside that *vtable*);
  and then a call like `p->print(std::cout);` would be translated almost like
  `p->_vptr.print$fun(p,&std::cout);` ... In addition, the compiler would generate as constant tables various virtual method tables (one per class).

<sup>NB: things are more complex with multiple or virtual inheritance.</sup>

In both cases, member functions don't eat any additional space in the object. If it is non-virtual, it is just a plain function (in the code segment). If it is virtual, it shares a slot in the virtual method table.

NB. If you compile with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (i.e. with `g++`) or with a [Clang](https://clang.llcm.org/) (so `clang++`) you could pass it e.g. the `-fdump-tree-all` flag: it will produce hundreds of dump files showing partly -in a dumped textual form- some internal representations of the compiler, which you could inspect with a pager (e.g. `less`) or a textual editor. You could also use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) or look at the assembly code produced with `g++ -S -fverbose-asm -O1` ....

Comment: Great answer, I can't believe it has so few up-votes!

Comment: Another addition and possibly a prerequisite to all other books mentioned is: Computer Organization and Design by David Patterson et al. This book starts at the beginning on how computers are structured and takes you on a journey through the years of computer design.

Answer (score 2):

All local non static variables and Non virtual functions are saved in code/text segment.

All static and global variables are saved in static data segment.

Class with virtual functions or inherited from a class with virtual functions will inserted a vptr pointer by compiler. Vptr points to a virtual function table which has number of functions slots. Each slot contains the function address which is stored in the code segment.

Answer (score -3):

To understand this you need to learn about memory layout of a program. the code will be shared by the objects. and all objects will have their own copy of data.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects) and to know about code and data segments can read memory layout of c/ c++ program http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch10s04.html

Comment: It would be helpful to provide links to the resources/topics you mentioned in your answer.