# this is not a real pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I am reading something about [virtual table](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/). When it comes to pointer `__vptr`,
it is stated that by the author

> Unlike the `*this` pointer, which is actually a function parameter used by the compiler to resolve self-references, `*__vptr` is a real pointer. Consequently, it makes each class object allocated bigger by the size of one pointer.

What does it mean here by saying `this` is actually a function parameter? And `this` is not a real pointer?

Comment: The tutorial you linked to fully answers and explains your question. What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @RedRoboHood Actually, I don't find it that clear in the tutorial, and I believe the question is correctly formulated.

Comment: The tutorial conveys dangerously misleading information. What is described is **one possible way** to implement virtual functions. This is neither defined in the C++ standard, nor is it necessarily implemented this way by any given implementation. Although V-tables are a common implementation, this is not strictly a requirement, and most certainly not part of the C++ language.

Comment: `*this` could not be a pointer. `this` could.

Comment: The terminology in the tutorial is confusing. It is using dereferencing syntax on what it is calling a *pointer*. I would avoid tutorials and go for a *recommended* book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both pointers are real in the sense that they store an address of something else in memory. By "real" the author means "stored within the class", as opposed to `this` pointer, which is passed to member functions without being stored in the object itself. Essentially, the pointer to `__vptr` is part of the object, while `this` pointer is not.

Comment: Where `this` is stored then?

Comment: @Allanqunzi Like any other function parameter, pointer `this` is transient, it is not necessarily stored at all. When you invoke a member function, the compiled code takes the address of the object on which you call the function, and passes that address as `this` pointer to the member function. Once the member function has finished, the `this` pointer is gone.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "transient pointer". Now *that*'s cool vocabulary :p

Answer (score 3):

`this` is *always* a hidden *implicit* formal argument. Practically speaking, every non `static` member function of a `class` is getting an implicit first argument which is `this`

so in

```
class Foo {
  int x; // a field, i.e. an instance variable
  void bar(double x);
};
```

the `Foo::bar` function has two arguments, exactly as if it was the C (not C++) function

```
void Foo__bar(Foo* mythis, double x);
```

And actually, [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and the compiler is transforming the first into a very close equivalent of the second. (I am using `mythis` instead of `this` because `this` is a keyword in C++).

In principle, the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) of your implementation could mandate a different passing convention for `this` (e.g. use another machine register) and for other explicit arguments. In practice, it often does not. On my Linux system the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) (its figure 3.4 page 21) defines a [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) that passes `this` (and first pointer formal argument to C function) in `%rdi` [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).

Practically speaking, in C++, most -but not all- member functions are small (defined inside the `class`) and [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) by the [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (and the latest [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and C++14 standards have been written with optimizing compilers in mind; see also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065)). In that case, the question of where is `this` stored becomes practically meaningless... (because of the inlining).

The [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (vtable) is generally an *implicit* first pointer *field* (or instance variable) of objects, but things could become more complex, e.g. with virtual [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). the vtable data itself (the addresses of `virtual` functions) is generated by the compiler. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119456/841108).

In theory, a C++ implementation could provide the [dynamic method dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) by another mechanism than vtable. In practice, I know no C++ implementation doing that.