# Does using "this" keyword in c++ have any impact on performance?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, heap-memory

For quite a long time I've been using javascript where `this` keyword is mandatory. Now, I'm programming in c++ but habit of using `this` keyword remained. But the real question is - Does using `this` keyword have any negative impact on performance (as in unnecessary memory access)? I mean - is code omitting `this` more optimization friendly for compiler or it completely doesn't matter? Because well strictly theoretically, referring to `this` is kind of referring to pointer, like `opcode $reg0, [$reg1]` in assembler, which could add one more memory reference in code but i guess it should be handled by compiler in more clever way than just typical pointer, am i right?

Personally I prefer using `this` because I feel a bit lost in code which doesn't use it as i don't know if some variables are members or they're local or global or what, but if it'd cause performance issues I could probably force myself to avoid it.

Comment: There's no difference. Write whatever you prefer.

Comment: You can use [gcc.godbolt.org](http://goo.gl/t7ncvy) to add and remove `this->` and see if the generated assembly changes. (It does not, even without optimizations.)

Comment: @zenith: I think questions about optimization are completely confused. Adding `this->` is a pure syntax-level detail. The *meaning* of expression is absolutely the same, and of course you need to interpret a member name relative to some object instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (for C++11 or better) would very probably generate the *same* binary code for `this->field` and for `field`, and likewise for `this->memberfun(2,3)` and `memberfun(2,3)`.

<sup>(probably, even *without* optimization, the same -inefficient- code would be produced; but I am not sure of that)</sup>

Sometimes (notably when coding templates) `this`  is required because omitting it has different meaning (I forgot for which weird cases).

Of course, the *compilation time* might be slightly different. But you should not care.

Some coding conventions require, or (more often) on the contrary forbid, using `this` for readability reasons. Choose whatever convention you like, but be consistent.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837054/841108) explaining how practically `this`  is handled on Linux x86-64 ABI.

Comment: What would an unoptimizing compiler do?

Comment: @KerrekSB: we don't care. If you do, examine the generated assembler code (e.g. compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -fverbose-asm -O0 -S`)

Comment: What I'm saying is that this claim doesn't make sense. The instance reference is implied in either spelling and necessitates the same code. Optimization has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I am not sure of that. Perhaps some compilers are putting explicit `this`  on the call stack (but keep the *implicit* `this` in some register).

Answer (score 4):

> But the real question is - Does using this keyword have any negative impact on performance (as in unnecessary memory access)?

no.

> which could add one more memory reference in code but i guess it should be handled by compiler in more clever way than just typical pointer, am i right?

yes

:-)