# What does compiler really do when a class inline function is called?

Tags: c++, class, inline

None static member functions implicitly have the `this` pointer. So these inline functions will not be replaced by compiler when they are called outside the class, am I right? This seems that usage of class inline functions is very restrictive!

Comment: C doesn't have classes, so that's a done deal. I can't make much sense out of the question though, could you clarify, with code samples maybe?

Comment: Why do you think that having the implicit `this` argument has something to do with inlining?

Comment: The compiler can inline any function it wants, as long as it ensures information is passed around correctly and the code behaves as required.   What a given compiler does, however, depends on the compiler.

Comment: This logic is false. There is no connection between the first sentence and the second. The former does not imply/cause the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimizing compiler can [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) as it wishes.

For example, you might compile *and link* an entire program with `g++ -flto -O2` (link-time whole program [optimization option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...).

<sup>(caveat: using `g++ -flto -O2` would slow down significantly your build process; basically everything is compiled nearly "twice", once at "compile" time, once at "link" time, where GIMPLE representation gets re-optimized)</sup>

You'll be surprised by what function calls get inlined (a lot of them could be). It is unrelated to static or not functions marked or not as `inline`.

So you should not *care* about inlining (it is an implementation and optimization detail), but you *hope* that the compiler will do a good job.

<sup>(sometimes with `g++` you want to disable most inlining to ease debugging with `gdb`; then compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -fno-inline -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g`)</sup>

> So these inline functions will not be replaced by compiler when they are called outside the class, am I right?

You are wrong, `this` is just an *implicit* argument (see also [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837054/841108)), and of course compilers are often inlining calls to member functions. In *practice* C++ would be inefficient if compilers did not that optimization (since many member functions -e.g. getters and [setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method)- are quite short and quick).

Remember that C++ is a *specification* written in some report (it is not a compiler). Inlining is a quality of implementation issue, and may or not happen.

If you care about what do the compiler really does (and you should not care, but you need to avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code), ask it to show the generated assembler code. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` to get a `foo.s` assembler file from a  `foo.cc` translation unit.

Comment: You can use `-fno-fat-lto-objects` to prevent double compilation.

Comment: But still, LTO compilation is slow

Comment: But not twice, as you wrote.

Comment: Sort of "twice". Improved

Answer (score 2):

When an inline member function is called the compiler does what it does for any function call: prepare the arguments and invoke the function. Any function call is subject to inlining. Some functions cannot be inlined ([e.g. functions using `alloca` or vararg functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html), functions whose definitions are not available), but member functions do not prevent inlining.

Comment: You mean that "some functions would not be inlined". A very clever compiler could in theory inline a function using `alloca` or `va_arg`; in  *practice* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is not able *yet* to do that, however with a lot of work you might make it do that if you really wanted to (e.g. by spending months to code a GCC plugin doing so)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It could in theory. However, I thought that it is worth mentioning some of the existing limitations.