# Pointer to a base virtual member function

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, pointer-to-member

Is there a way to make a pointer on member function in base class if it is a virtual function and it is overridden in derived class?

Consider the code as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Base
{
    virtual void g() const
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void g() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    (d.*(&Base::g))();
    std::mem_fn(&Base::g)(d);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints ‘Derived’ twice despite I make a pointer on Base::g. Is there a way to keep function g virtual and overridden and get member function pointer that will print ‘Base’ for d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might define a non-virtual function `real_g` called from `g` so code

```
struct Base
{
  void real_g() const {
    std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void g() const { real_g(); };
};
```

Then later in `main`

```
std::mem_fn(&Base::real_g)(d);
```

See wikipage on [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and the C++ standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better. Read also a [good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your C++ compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837054/841108) answer (explaining naively what are vtables, in simple cases)

Comment: That feels like cheating :)

Comment: No; and a good optimizing compiler generates equivalent code anyway

Comment: Yet it does. The biggest problem here is that enabling the class to work in a manner desired by OP requires class modifications. First of all, it might not be feasible at all (class might come from third-party library), second of all, it causes expansion of functions members. I do not claim to know how to achieve what OP wants (otherwise I would post an answer), but I do not like this answer either.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the question of "Is there a way to keep function g virtual and overridden and get member function pointer that will print 'Base of d'

Comment: @thelizardking34 technically it does - `g` is still overridden and virtual - but yes, it feels like cheating on the technicality.

Comment: @SergeyA If you're going to add extra functions; why not just wrap it in a lambda instead of changing the functionality of the class; and depending on the compiler to make it better?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Could we do std::mem_fn(&Base::g)(static_cast<Base>(d))?

Comment: @JimmyLoyola, by doing so you will create a copy of d, which is not what was expected: create a pointer/callable function to Base::g of existing object d.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the base function

```
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.g();
    
    Base* b = &d;
    b->Base::g();
    
    //or 
    d.Base::g();

    //or

    auto callLater = [&d]() { d.Base::g();};
    callLater();
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Derived
Base
Base
Base
```

This can be made a pointer to the function; but it needs be to the member function Base::g() of the object being pointed to.