# First member of class of C++ object

Tags: c++, class-structure

I know the following is bad but I was under the impression that the first member of class is the starting address of the class. Is it wrong ?

```
   class A{
      public:
       int a;
       int b;
   };
  
   class B{
     public :
       int x;
   };

   int main()
   {
        B *pb=new B();
        A *pa=(A*)pb;
        pa->a++;
   }
```

I was under the impression that `pb->x` would be incremented by 1. Is it always true or undefined ? Why does it change when we have user defined constructors or virtual functions ?

Comment: Yes. It is bad! So bad that the answer should be irrelevant.

Comment: Your question doesn't matter! All what you can do with this is bad design and mostly undefined behaviour. Simple answer: Never do that! It maybe works today but is not defined that it will work tomorrow or with any other compiler.

Answer (score 4):

This holds only true if your class is of `standard_layout` type. This you can test using the type trait [is_standard_layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout)

```
 std::cout << std::is_standard_layout<A>::value << '\n';
 std::cout << std::is_standard_layout<B>::value << '\n';
```

For other classes, you have additional information stored in memory, which is compiler specific and not standardized. You can have a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects) where some memory layouts are discussed and showed.

For your second example/question the standard has the following quote (5.2.10/7, N3337 draft):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”,
> the result is static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)) if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1,
> or if either type is void. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are
> no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

If I read and interpret this correctly, then your example is unspecified, as the alignment requirements of A are bigger that those of B. However, the other way should be ok, e.g:

```
int main()
{
    A *pa=new A();
    B *pb=reinterpret_cast<B*>(pa);
    pb->x++;
    std::cout << pa->a;
}
```

Comment: You can cast a pointer to an object of a standard layout type to a pointer to its first member, but I'm not completely sure about this one. Can you add a supporting quote from The Standard?

Comment: Most of those rules are fairly intuitive, but rules #3 and #6 seem ridiculous to me, and I can't even understand what #5 is trying to say.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart #3 is to allow compilers to reorder class members based on access. #6 needs to be read in conjunction with #5; if the class has a non-static data member then all its base classes must be empty (per #5), but if the first non-static data member is of the same type as a base class then the compiler must give it and the (empty) base-class subobject distinct addresses because they are distinct objects.

Comment: @BoBTFish I added the section of the standard which describes this. I can't say if I interpreted it correctly, but as it seems, casting from A to B should be fine, while casting from B to A is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

You've violated strict aliasing by casting the pointer to another class. You can only cast it to the type of the first member, if your class is standard-layout.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you are absolutely wrong, you can never take anything like that for granted, those are compiler specific contracts that C++ does not guarantee.

I believe you confused classes with C++ arrays: For example the pointer to the first member of a char array is the same as the pointer to that array.

Comment: Any supporting link to specifications?

Comment: I don't quite understand why this answer is downvoted

Comment: Because it's incorrect. Standard-layout does in fact absolutely make this guarantee and even the original C spec did it.

Comment: what if the first member is a virtual function in a hierarchy ? what if the class is itself part of a hierarchy ? I think either you are not certain about what you're talking about (with respect) or you are not considering all the possibilities...

Comment: We didn't see any virtual methods in the code shown though.

Comment: @jaffar exaclty this is what standard-layout guarantees. If your class has any of those 'obstacles', it is not Standard-layout. On the other hand, if your class is standard-layout, it is well defined.

Comment: @MatthiasB yes you're correct, the original question though makes no attempt at any clarification so I thought 'no' was the safer answer given the "obstacles" that could be present