# are object just piece of memory in c++?

Tags: c++, object

I have a question that I don't figure out about object.
does making a object in c++ create a piece memory where all the  data are stored inside  that memory?

Comment: I think it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects

Comment: How else might it work?

Comment: memory is not "created" on the fly (that would be actually quite cool) but allocated

Comment: Is human being just a piece of chemical elements in life?

Answer (score 0):

Proper term is "memory location".  An object  **may** have memory location that can be described by an  element of single primitive  type or a sequence of elements. An object have "storage". Neither term refers to any particular representation in physical memory, it can be an abstraction, a range of RAM or cache storage units or a CPU register.
A statically defined constexpr object might not have a memory location at all, but will have storage. Difference between storage and memory location is that latter can be adressed by other, external in relation to this object, means, e.g. by dereferencing pointer, by passing a reference to a function,  by pointer arythmetics within range of an array of objects, etc.