# Is the pointer from casting to base gurenteed to be a pointer into the memory region of the derived object

Tags: c++, pointers, standards

Given this code:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

struct base{
    virtual ~base() = default;
};

class derived: public base{
public:
    int x;
};

using byte = unsigned char;


int main() {
    byte data[sizeof(derived)];
    derived d;
    memcpy(data, &d, sizeof(derived));
    base* p = static_cast<base*>(reinterpret_cast<derived*>(data));
    const auto offset = (long)data - (long)p;
    assert(offset < sizeof(derived)); // <-- Is this defined?
}
```

As my comment asks, is this defined behavior by the standard? i.e does casting to base guarantee a pointer to the region occupied by the derived being cast? From my testing it works on gcc and clang, but I am wondering if it works cross platform too (obviously this version assumes 64bit pointers)

Comment: Don't you want placement new instead of `memcpy`. `static_cast<base*>` should not be the issue, but `reinterpret_cast<derived*>` cast should (there are no objects in your buffer).

Comment: @Jarod42 In my actual code I am using placement new and manually calling the dtor and placement copy constructing etc, this was just for sake of example. Also the memcpy should be valid afaik, the value of that int is gonna be garbage since its uninitialized but the data of it is still allocated (on the stack)

Comment: Reading not initialized `x` is another issue (as potential issue with alignment); My point is that, pedantically, there is no object in buffer `data` (no lifetime has begun for any `derived` instance). placement new would be correct though, it is just your simplification for the question which is "problematic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### potentially wrong alignment

your `data` array is a char array, so its alignment will be 1 byte.
your class however contains an `int` member, so its alignment will be at least 4 bytes.

So you `data` array is not sufficiently aligned to even contain a derived object.

You can easily fix this by providing an alignment of your data array that is at least that of `derived` or greater, e.g.:

```cpp
alignas(alignof(derived)) byte data[sizeof(derived)];
```

([godbolt demonstrating the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/8szW5f1s8))

you can also use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) for this if you want.

##### using memcpy on classes is not always safe

Using `memcpy` on classes will only work if they're [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) (so a byte-wise copy would be identical to calling the copy constructor). Your class isn't trivially copyable due to the virtual destructor, so `memcpy` isn't allowed to copy the class.

You can easily check this with [`std::is_trivially_copyable_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable):

```cpp
std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<derived> << std::endl;
```

You can fix this easily by calling the copy-constructor instead of using `memcpy`:

```cpp
alignas(alignof(derived)) char data[sizeof(derived)];
derived d;
derived* derivedInData = new (data) derived(d);
```

##### virtual inheritance, multiple inheritance and other shenanigans

How classes will be layed out in memory is [implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects), so you basically have no guarantees how the compiler will lay out your class hierarchy.

However there are a few things you can count on:

- `sizeof(cls)` will always return the size `cls` needs, including all it's base classes, even when it uses virtual and / or multiple inheritance. ([sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof))

  > When applied to a class type, the result is the number of bytes occupied by a complete object of that class, including any additional padding required to place such object in an array.
- placement new will construct an object and return a pointer to it that is within the given buffer.
- `static_cast<>` to baseclass is always defined

##### the actual answer

Yes, the base class pointer must always point to somewhere within your buffer, since it's a part of the derived class. However where exactly it'll be in the buffer is implementation-defined, so you should not rely on it.

The same thing is true about the pointer returned from placement new - it might be to the beginning of the array or somewhere else (e.g. array allocation), but it'll always be within the data array.

So as long as you stick to one of those patterns:

```cpp
struct base { int i; }
struct derived : base { int j; };

alignas(alignof(derived)) char data[sizeof(derived)];
derived d;
memcpy(data, &d, sizeof(derived)); // trivially copyable
derived* ptrD = reinterpret_cast<derived*>(data);
base* ptrB = static_cast<base*>(ptrD);
```

/

```cpp
struct base { int i; virtual ~base() = default; }
struct derived : base { int j; };

alignas(alignof(derived)) char data[sizeof(derived)];
derived d;
derived* ptrD = new(data) derived(d); // not trivially copyable
base* ptrB = static_cast<base*>(ptrD);
ptrD->~derived(); // remember to call destructor
```

your assertions should hold and the code should be portable.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the pointer from casting to base gurenteed to be a pointer into the memory region of the derived object

Not necessarily in general. If the base is virtual, and the derived object in question isn't the most derived object, then in such case the virtual base may be outside the memory of the derived object.

But outside of that corner case, for example such as in the example code, the base sub object is indeed guaranteed to be within the derived object. That's what "sub object" implies.

Comment: Assuming there is no virtual inheritance in the tree, is it defined?