# How to visualize layout of C++ struct/class

Tags: c++, gcc

What is the best way to visualize the memory layout of a C++ class/struct, compiled by GCC?

I added the GCC switch `-fdump-lang-class` to my C++ compile options but it didn't output anything to stdout, nor did I notice any files `.class` files created.

I just want to see the size/offsets of class/data members.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects

Comment: If you need The Best way, than `sizeof()`, `offsetof()`, `printf(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pahole. It is a swiss army tool for this kind of things.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/pahole.1.html

For example, say you have this test.cpp file

```cpp
struct A {
        int i;
        char c;
        double x;
};

void doit( A& a ) {
        a.i = 1;
        a.c = 0;
        a.x = 1.0;
}
```

Let's compile it into a shared library

```bash
$ g++ test.cpp -shared -ggdb -o libtest.so
$ ls -l libtest.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 awesome awesome 16872 Aug 12 20:15 libtest.so
```

Then run pahole on the binary (with debug information)

```bash
$ pahole libtest.so
struct A {
        int                        i;                    /*     0     4 */
        char                       c;                    /*     4     1 */
        /* XXX 3 bytes hole, try to pack */
        double                     x;                    /*     8     8 */

        /* size: 16, cachelines: 1, members: 3 */
        /* sum members: 13, holes: 1, sum holes: 3 */
        /* last cacheline: 16 bytes */
};
```

You can also provide a class name with the `-C <classname>` argument

```bash
$ pahole -C A libtest.so
struct A {
        int                        i;                    /*     0     4 */
        char                       c;                    /*     4     1 */
        /* XXX 3 bytes hole, try to pack */
        double                     x;                    /*     8     8 */

        /* size: 16, cachelines: 1, members: 3 */
        /* sum members: 13, holes: 1, sum holes: 3 */
        /* last cacheline: 16 bytes */
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Strangely it doesn't seem to be finding every class/struct. Can it handle templated classes/could this be the reason?

Comment: Found the solution: --show_private_classes

Comment: You need to compile with some debug info too ‘-g’