# Can you control struct layout in c++ while extending?

Tags: c++, struct

In C, I can control the layout of a struct which inherits its members from two other structs as follows (using the `-fms-extensions` extensions):

```
typedef struct foo {
  int a;
} foo;

typedef struct bar {
  int b;
} bar;

typedef struct baz {
  struct foo;
  int c;
  struct bar;
} baz;

int main() {
  baz b;
  b.a = 42;
  b.b = 99;
  b.c = 99;
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PcdeeMGcz

In the disassembly you can see that c is in between a and b. How can you do this in C++?

```
typedef struct foo {
  int a;
} foo;

typedef struct bar {
  int b;
} bar;

typedef struct baz : foo, bar {
  int c;
} baz;

int main() {
  baz b;
  b.a = 42;
  b.b = 99;
  b.c = 99;
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4qfx89sEj

This attempt puts c in front of both a and b. I could change the order of the extends to change the layout of those, but I dont know how I would put c in between them (without using an intermediary struct). Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This sounds very much like "implementation defined behaviour". I'm not sure there's a standard (or Portable) way to do this.

Comment: See [memory layout C++ objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1632600).

Comment: What exactly are your requirements here? If this is just about the layout, you wouldn't need the Miscrosoft extension at all and it would work the same way in C and C++. If you also have the requirement that the "inherited" members are directly accessible from `b` without any intermediate name, while still not needing to add individual declarations for the members in the "derived" class, then no, that's not possible in either standard C or C++. If you are fine with adding declarations for each "inherited" member, the matter is different (but then the question seems kind of pointless).

Comment: Also, if you are asking only about one specific compiler/platform, please make that clear. `-fms-extensions` is obviously not something that works "_In C_" in general.

Comment: In C++, you can use aggregation rather than inheritance.   That gives some control (by ordering of the declaration of members in `struct`s and classes.  But that does not give complete control - there are limits (e.g. struct padding, ensuring your types are trivial/POD, etc).    But those are the same limits (implicitly or explicitly) on such control in C.    [Use of non-standard extensions, like `-fms-extensions` for C, rely on specific support by implementations].

Comment: @user17732522 the intention here is to make sure that serialization/deserialization works properly. The struct is data only and so we write/read (mmap) it straight to disk. For performance reasons, the ordering of the members matters. So, I wanted a way to make sure the ordering stuck properly.

Comment: @user17732522 I would appreciate as general a solution as possible, but oftentimes there is no general solution so I am forced to settle for platform specific ones / extensions

Comment: @chacham15 If _only_ the ordering is relevant to you and not the convenience of accessing each member of the "inherited" being reachable directly by member access expression on the "derived" class, then there is no need to use inheritance or the MS extension. Just place non-static members of the "inherited" types in the "derived" class as the already-posted answer shows.

Comment: @chacham15 Of course, there are then still no layout guarantees in general. Class layout, in particular where padding is added, is not standardized and instead specified by the applicable ABI, but usually is easy to reason about if you consider size and alignment requirements of the members. (That's going to apply with the MS extension as well I am sure.)

Comment: Yeah, we have assertions in our test suite to make sure that expectations match reality. Layout is the primary concern, but access is also important, so I'm trying to achieve both.

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to do in C++, and similar to C.

```
struct foo {
  int a;
};

struct bar {
  int b;
};

struct baz {
  foo f;
  int c;
  bar b;
};

int main() {
  baz b;
  b.f.a = 42;
  b.b.b = 99;
  b.c = 99;
}
```

Comment: I think OP's goal is to _not_ have to use `b.f.a` but be able to reference `b.a` directly, while maintaining the layout automatically. Otherwise there would be no point in them using a non-standard extension in the original code.

Comment: Indeed that is correct @user17732522

Comment: @chacham15 But that's not what you answered me in the comments under the question. Do you have _both_ requirements mentioned here and there?

Comment: @chacham15 Anyway, if you have both requirements and the MS extension doesn't support the construct, I think you are out-of-luck without any modification of the syntax (e.g. accessing through member functions instead of data members).