Address of 'this' pointer in Inheritance hierarchy
I was debugging some legacy code and while doing that found some inconsistency in the address of this pointer in the class hierarchy like this:
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

class ROOT1 {
   public:
    ROOT1() {}
    void printsomething() { printf("ROOT1::printsomething %p\n", this); }
    virtual ~ROOT1() {}
};

class SUBROOT : public ROOT1 {
   public:
    SUBROOT() {}
    void printsomething() { printf("SUBROOT::printsomething %p\n", this); }
    virtual ~SUBROOT() {}
};

class ROOT2 {
   public:
    ROOT2() {}
    virtual ~ROOT2() {}
    void printsomething() { printf("ROOT2::printsomething %p\n", this); }
};

class CHILD : public ROOT2, public SUBROOT {
   public:
    CHILD() {}
    virtual ~CHILD() {}
    void printsomething() { printf("CHILD::printsomething %p\n", this); }
};
class GRANDCHILD : public CHILD {
   public:
    GRANDCHILD() {}
    virtual ~GRANDCHILD() {}
    void printsomething() { printf("GRANDCHILD::printsomething %p\n", this); }
};

int main() {
    try {
        GRANDCHILD* line = new GRANDCHILD;
        ROOT1* root1 = static_cast<ROOT1*>(line);
        SUBROOT* subroot = static_cast<SUBROOT*>(line);
        CHILD* child = static_cast<CHILD*>(line);
        ROOT2* root2 = static_cast<ROOT2*>(line);

        root2->printsomething();
        root1->printsomething();
        subroot->printsomething();
        child->printsomething();
        line->printsomething();

    } catch (const char* s) {
        printf("Throw %s, %d\n", s, sizeof(std::vector<void*>));
    }
}

LIVE
The output I am getting is:
ROOT2::printsomething 0x23cf2b0
ROOT1::printsomething 0x23cf2b8
SUBROOT::printsomething 0x23cf2b8
CHILD::printsomething 0x23cf2b0
GRANDCHILD::printsomething 0x23cf2b0

There is a difference between the addresses of 'this' pointer. If I just swap the order of inheritance, the addresses changes along the class hierarchy. i.e.
class CHILD :  public SUBROOT, public ROOT2

LIVE
Output:
ROOT2::printsomething 0xc9b2b8
ROOT1::printsomething 0xc9b2b0
SUBROOT::printsomething 0xc9b2b0
CHILD::printsomething 0xc9b2b0
GRANDCHILD::printsomething 0xc9b2b0

What could be the reason?

can't replicate, they are still inconsistent godbolt demo of gcc clang MSVC

i would be more interested in knowing what form of bugged compiler you are using that would produce ROOT2:: from child with your code .... technically your compiler would be bugged if it produces that result, but your code also has a typo, so i am not sure who to blaim

This is normal and expected. Try to draw the layout of either version of CHILD.

@AhmedAEK upcast with static_cast is always OK. Then it's multiple inheritance, isn't it expected that the subobjects on different branchs have different address?

@Oersted all versions of the code above will show CHILD::printsomething not ROOT2::printsomething, except when i added it myself to show that it still has different addrss, the code above should not produce ROOT2::printsomething except if the compiler is bugged or the question is wrong.

The second part of the question is not correct. I realised it by patching the snippet. In both cases, you're getting different addresses, which, IMHO, should be expected. Checking static_cast rules for upcast right now.

for prvalue pointer to derived, the conversion to a prvalue pointer to a base subobject gives the address of this subobject. No reason that it should be the same as the derived object. Here we're dealing with lvalues but I would the behavior to be the same. I'm just missing the right reference.

This old closed question essentially explains object layout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632600/memory-layout-c-objects From there it should be understandable why the this pointer changes.

My understanding: BASE* p1 = new BASE;DERIVED* p2 = static_cast<DERIVED*>(p1); p1 undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, then implicit pointer conversion kicks in as stated in a previous comment, then p2 is initialized by a prvalue of type DERIVED*. Is it correct?

last nail in the coffin: ROOT2 and ROOT1 subobjects of GRANDCHILD are unrelated, they cannot share a same memory location, thus their addresses are necessarily different.

It is a matter of multiple inheritance.
Exactly to avoid multiple inheritance in java, a java class can extend only one single class, though then implement several interfaces (primarily this-bodyless APIs).
With multiple inheritance CHILD has a ROOT2 this and a SUBROOT this.
This difference in addresses are due to the virtual method table of method pointers that are stored in the classes this. To pick the right inherited printsomething.
BTW you see here a clash of printsomethings of two different class lines in CHILD. This was thought to need avoidance in java.

printsomething is not virtual (otherwise the output should always be GRANDCHILD::printsomething I think: https://godbolt.org/z/TGvKad56d).

@Oersted yes a virtual would have been a minor ambiguity problem in C++ too. But I could not refrain from remarking on printsomething here.

btw, I can't find, so far, a constraint in C++ to give the same memory location to base objects, in single inheritance. Yet I think that all compilers do so and I may well have missed some part of the standard on this topic.

A new CHILD addesses an object (memory block) as CHILD*. There is no other "base" object. The same address is used as ROOT2*. The object contains a vtable of methods, where some virtual ROOT2 methods are replaced by overriden CHILD methods. This technique is used to implement inheritance in probably all compilers. Only SUBROOT has an offset address in the object, with the SUBROOT data fields and vtable. No requirement.

of course they are base subobjects. as far as I dug, only the order in which they are created is specified, not the memory layout. vtable and offsets are an implementation detail and thus are not described in the standard.

@Oersted I understand, a base suboject as part of the single object. These base objects need not (and indeed) have the same address, but are ">=" of the object, pointing in the same memory block. However for single inheritance it makes much sense to have identical addresses.
